# Trigger HTTP Outbound Gateway from non-spring managed class and receive response

Tags: spring, spring-integration-dsl, message-channel

I want to trigger a HTTP Outbound Gateway flow from a non-spring managed class and then receive a response within some timeframe. I set up the HTTP Outbound Gateway in my configuration class with message converters, transformers , rest template, splitters and aggregators just fine.

I trigger the HTTP Outbound Gateway Integration Flow from the non-spring managed class using MessageChannel.send(..) method on the gateway's input channel . But i want to know how i receive the response from the gateway's reply channel. What kind of channel do i need to use for the reply channel and how does the non-spring managed class fetch the response ?

I tried using a QueueChannel for the reply channel but got an error message about no poller been setup to poll from such a channel.